# memory stable C++ vector implementation

Tags: c++, vector

Is there available a variant of C++ std::vector (or functionally similar container) where the location of elements in memory is stable (at least up to reducing the extent)? I am expecting the implementation to be in fixed sized chunks rather than a single linear allocation. I am not looking for a std:: container but hoping someone has shared such an implementation that I might reuse.

Thanks

david

Comment: you mean std::array<> ?

Comment: @quantdev: That's not "functionally similar", since it's statically sized. `std::deque` would fit the bill though.

Comment: Stable in the sense of not changing when adding elements at the end, or not changing period, even when adding/removing elements at the beginning?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What is your use case?

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you want a `std::deque`, stores data in page sized chunks that remain stable until erased.

Comment: To be clear, "until erased" means "until *any* iterator except `begin()` or `end()` is erased". Same for `emplace` and `insert`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean a container that will keep the objects in place without reallocating/moving them (a pointer to the object will stay valid until the object gets removed from the container), in that case `std::list` is for you.